# Issue getting info out of array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get info out of this information:

```
Array (
    [result] => success
    [totalresults] => 1
    [startnumber] => 0
    [numreturned] => 1 
    [tickets] => Array (
        [ticket] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 7
                [tid] => 782755
                [deptid] => 1
                [userid] => 39
                [name] => Mark Lønquist
                [email] => mark.loenquist@outlook.com
                [cc] => 
                [c] => 79rzVBeJ
                [date] => 2013-04-25 16:14:24
                [subject] => test
                [status] => Open
                [priority] => Medium
                [admin] => 
                [attachment] => 
                [lastreply] => 2013-04-25 16:14:24 
                [flag] => 0
                [service] => 
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The results are printed using:

```
print_r($results);
```

Usually, I've been able to do a simple:

```
$var = $results['something'];
```

To get it out, but it wont work with this :( Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $results['something'] should work. Can you be more specific? Is there a particular something?

Comment: Add this to the top off your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see what the problem is...

Comment: I refuse to believe `it won't work with this` - as others have pointed out, show the errors you are getting.

Comment: if `$results['something']` won't work, then you need `$results['something']['somethingElse']`

Comment: I've updated the indentation to make it clearer. Perhaps this will shed light on the issue.

Comment: just in case, what exactly is the question ?

Comment: This is what I get if I do, lets say: echo $results['tid'];

error: Notice: Undefined index: tid in /home/ehssdk/public_html/newsite/do/do.tickets.php on line 19
EDIT!! echo $results['tickets']['ticket'][0]['tid']; works, but seems clumsy.. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: What if  there was more than 1 ticket? How would I go about getting all tid's?

Comment: You'd have to iterate (loop) through the tickets. What does the structure look like with multiple tickets in it?

Comment: Looks like this: http://pastebin.com/2ZE2VSLR

Comment: The loop part gave me the answer Wiseguy :) Thank you! please leave a answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reformatting the array you pasted, it becomes clear that some elements are nested several levels deep. (It's a "multidimensional array"; see [example #6](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-87) in the docs.) In those cases, you have to add additional brackets containing each successive key to reach the depth you want. For example, a sample from your `$results` array:

```
Array (
    [result] => success
    [totalresults] => 1
    ...
    [tickets] => Array (
        [ticket] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 7
                [tid] => 782755
                ...
            )
        )
    )
)
```

You simply need to do `$results['totalresults']` to access "totalresults", but to get "tid" you would need to use `$results['tickets']['ticket'][0]['tid']`.

---

If you want to get "tid" from all of the tickets when there are multiple, you will have to iterate (loop) over the array of tickets. Probably something like this (untested, but should be close enough for you to figure out):

```
foreach ($results['tickets']['ticket'] as $ticket) {
    echo $ticket['tid'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what the problem is with your `print_r()` you may add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your code.

Note that if you want to retrieve the value for a key such as 'totalresults' then `$results['totalresults']` would be sufficient.

However, if you want to get a key from one of the nested arrays such as `email` then you would have to use `$results['result']['tickets']['ticket'][0]['email']`.